# My carousel runs well except bullet javascipt

Tags: javascript

I put bullet. it's ok. Each bullet is linked to correct image. That's ok. but if i want to use bullet to change of image. It isn't ok. What the issue ? Thanks for your help. I've tried to put addEventListenre but it broke my code. and setInterval don't work to. It is an array where i takes data to build my code.

here is the html code :

```
<div id="banner">
            <img src="./assets/images/slideshow/slide1.jpg" alt="Banner print-it">
                    <p>Impressions tous formats <span>en boutique et en ligne</span></p>
            <img class="arrow_left" src="./assets/images/arrow_left.png" alt="image fleche gauche">
            <img class="arrow_right" src="./assets/images/arrow_right.png" alt="image fleche droite">
        <div class="dots">
        </div>
    </div>
```

```
const slides = [
    {
        "image":"slide1.jpg",
        "tagLine":"Impressions tous formats <span>en boutique et en ligne</span>"
    },
    {
        "image":"slide2.jpg",
        "tagLine":"Tirages haute définition grand format <span>pour vos bureaux et events</span>"
    },
    {
        "image":"slide3.jpg",
        "tagLine":"Grand choix de couleurs <span>de CMJN aux pantones</span>"
    },
    {
        "image":"slide4.png",
        "tagLine":"Autocollants <span>avec découpe laser sur mesure</span>"
    }
]
const banner = document.getElementById('#banner');
const left = document.querySelector('.arrow_left');
const right = document.querySelector('.arrow_right');
const imageElement = document.querySelector('#banner > img');
const nomElement = document.querySelector('#banner > p');

const numberOfSlide = slides.length;

let i = 0;
/* Create bullet (dot) */ 
function dots() {
    const dots = document.querySelector('.dots');
    for (let i = 0; i < numberOfSlide; i++) {
    const dot = document.createElement('span');
    dot.classList.add('dot');
    dots.appendChild(dot);
    if (i == 0) { 
        dots.children[i].classList.add('dot_selected');
    }
    }
 }
dots();

/* Link bullet to image (dot) */
 function selected() {
    const dot = document.getElementsByClassName('dot');
    for (let i = 0; i < dot.length; i++) {
        dot[i].classList.remove('dot_selected');
    }
    dot[i].classList.add('dot_selected');
 }
/* Link tagline and image to HTML*/
function showSlide() {
    imageElement.src = `./assets/images/slideshow/${slides[i].image}`;
    nomElement.innerHTML = slides[i].tagLine;
    console.log(imageElement);
    console.log(nomElement);
    selected();
}
/* Call function to move left */
left.addEventListener("click", function () {
    if (i == 0) {
        i = numberOfSlide - 1;
    }
    else {
        i--;
    }
        console.log(left);
        showSlide();
});
/* Call function to move right */   
right.addEventListener("click", function () {
    if (i == numberOfSlide - 1) {
        i = 0;
    } else {
            i++;
    }
    console.log(right);
    showSlide();
    console.log(showSlide);
});

interval = setInterval(showSlide, 5000);
```

Comment: Please  post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Just a tip: you can use modulus instead to keep your current slide index in-bound istead of `if (i == numberOfSlide - 1)`

Comment: what is modulus, i'm learning javascript. And i have thaat message in JSBIN console :

 "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'appendChild')

Comment: Please use google: "javascript modulus"

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the arrows and dots and delegate

Something like this (I cannot test since you did not post your HTML)

```js
let numberOfSlide = 10
let currentSlide = 0; // don't use i since it is used everywhere as an index counter
const banner = document.getElementById("banner");
const showSlide = () => console.log(currentSlide); // change the i in your showSlide for currentSlide

/* Create bullet (dot) */
document.querySelector('.dots').innerHTML = Array.from({ length: numberOfSlide }) // create an array of numberOfSlide entries
  .map(
    (_, i) => `<span class="dot${i===0?' dot_selected':''}"></span>` // use template literals 
  ).join(""); // join the spans together 

const dots = document.querySelectorAll('.dot');

banner.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.matches('.dot')) {
    dots.forEach((dot,i) => {
      if (tgt === dot) currentSlide = i;
      dot.classList.toggle('dot_selected', tgt === dot);
    });  
  } else {
    const dir = tgt.matches('.arrow_right') ? 1 : -1;
    currentSlide += dir;
    if (currentSlide < 0) currentSlide = 0;
    else if (currentSlide >= numberOfSlide) currentSlide = numberOfSlide - 1;
    dots[currentSlide].click()
  }
  showSlide();
});
```

```css
span::after {
  content: "*"
}

.dot_selected {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="banner">
  <img src="./assets/images/slideshow/slide1.jpg" alt="Banner print-it">
  <p>Impressions tous formats <span>en boutique et en ligne</span></p>
  <img class="arrow_left" src="./assets/images/arrow_left.png" alt="image fleche gauche">
  <img class="arrow_right" src="./assets/images/arrow_right.png" alt="image fleche droite">
  <div class="dots">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your solution doesn't work

Comment: Ok, look again. I fixed quite a few things

Comment: Sorry. Thank for your help but i'm a beginner in javascript. do you have a simple solution to update my code with what I possibly forgot, I don't know the map. and I want to be able to understand the code outside the I don't understand. Sorry for the inconvenient

Comment: Sorry. I am not going to write code I do not like. [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is not hard to grasp

Comment: I added some comments

Comment: thak for your help